# How can I send data from an external php file that is connected to an external database to my extension's content-script.js?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm building an extension that extracts DOMs from a website(not mine) and automates a button click with filling some inputs.

The inputs are filled with values that I extract from my database that I created(not the website's database). The extraction is done with php, but the filling is with javascript in the content-script.js. What I want is, make php file sends those values to my content-script files and wait for a response which is a click and then updates the database.

When I use XMLHttpRequest, I get an error that I can't access and it's blocked by CORS policy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function reqListener () {
   console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://localhost:8012/extension/php/getIntervenant.php");
oReq.send();
});
```

my manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1",
  "name": "Extention ",
  "description": "Extracting and attributing",
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["link here"],
      "js":["jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "content-script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Extention"
    },
    "permissions": ["unlimitedStorage"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
"permissions": ["unlimitedStorage"]
```

Should be:

```
"permissions": [
      "url1",
      "url2"
    ]
```

Check: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr